# How to Set arrays in other scripts

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Hi I am making a Multiplayer shooter in unity and im using arrays and need help

My situation is I want to make an unboxing system that chooses a random array and then set it to the list of the classes array list please help.
Please tell me if this would choose a random array: Classes[Random];
and also I need to know how to set an array from a different script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpawnNew : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] Classes;
    public GameObject player;
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public Camera spawnCam;
    public AudioListener spawnListener;
    public bool spawned = false;


    void ClassList(){

        Classes = new GameObject[10];
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (Network.isServer || Network.isClient)
        {
            if (!spawned)
            {
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 10 - 50, Screen.height / 10 - 25, 100, 50), "Spawn"))
                {
                    SpawnPlayer();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void SpawnPlayer()
    {
        spawned = true;
        int random = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
        Network.Instantiate(player, spawnPoints[random].position, spawnPoints[random].rotation, 0);
        spawned = true;
        spawnCam.enabled = false;
        spawnListener.enabled = false;
        spawned = true;
    }

    public void Die()
    {
        Screen.lockCursor = false;
        spawned = false;
        spawnCam.enabled = true;
        spawnListener.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i didnt understand what you want

Comment: you rarely/never use arrays in Unity for any reason.  Use List<>

Answer (score 0):

First of all your array is not initialized. You have to make sure the array is populated before calling SpawnPlayer method, otherwise this will through a NullReferenceException.
Yes, this `int random = Random.Range(0, yourArray.Length);` would give you a random index within your array.
You can access your array / method from within another script like this

```
GameObject yourObject = GameObject.Find("GameObjectNameThatHasYourScriptAttachedToIt");
if(yourObject !=null){
    yourObject.GetComponent<SpawnNew>().Classes = someOtherArray;
    // or if you want to access the method 
    // yourObject.GetComponent<SpawnNew>().SpawnPlayer();
}
```

Comment: that is possible, but it never hurts to make sure it is indeed set :)

Comment: I don't understand why the down-vote...is there something wrong with this solution?